# Why Ubuntu uses eglibc instead of glibc?

Tags: c, glibc

I checked for the libc version on my Ubuntu `64bit` `12.10` machine by issuing the command `ldd --version`.

I saw that Ubuntu uses `eglibc` instead of `glibc`. As `egiblc` is for embedded machines, Is there a specific reason why Ubuntu uses it instead of the standard glibc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ubuntu is based on debian. This is an abridgment of [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_GLIBC):

> On 6 May 2009, it was announced that Debian would move from the GNU C
>   Library to EGLIBC, citing problems with the development process of
>   glibc. Debian and several of its derivatives now ship EGLIBC
>   instead of glibc. EGLIBC is free software licensed under the GNU LGPL.

These are the reasons (form [Debian is switching to EGLIBC](http://blog.aurel32.net/47)):

> The EGLIBC is a variant of the GLIBC which stays source and binary
>   compatible with the original GLIBC. While primarily targeted for
>   embedded architectures, it has some really nice points:
>
> - More friendly upstream (especially with regard to embedded    architectures): “Encourage cooperation, communication, civility, and
>     respect among developers” (as opposed to this).
> - Stable branch with fixes for important bugs (a real one, not like the GLIBC one which is left unchanged).
> - Better support for embedded architectures.
> - Support for different shells (GLIBC only supports bash).
> - Support for building with -Os.
> - Configurable components (do we really need NIS or RPC support in debian-installer?).
> - Better testsuite for optimized or biarch packages.

Comment: One of many likely consequences of the "broken" development process and a complete lack of security rigor: the GHOST vuln https://community.qualys.com/blogs/laws-of-vulnerabilities/2015/01/27/the-ghost-vulnerability My favorite part of the above article is *denying* the security threat. A codebase that is too large, poorly engineered and lacks a productive, functioning community likely contains many vulnerabilities... like playing whac-a-mole on a flea-bitten POODLE.  Don't use glibc.  Period.

Comment: glibc is a pita for sure, I'm fighting with its inability to be statically linked, which makes cross compiling just that much more annoying.  What are the alternatives though, now that eglibc hit end of life?

Answer (score 8):

Except they have now switched back:

Since the beginning of 2014, the official homepage states that EGLIBC is no longer being developed, since its "goals are now being addressed directly in GLIBC", and Debian has switched back to glibc[4] for the Debian 8.0 (Jessie) release. -- Wikipedia

Comment: Ubuntu has switched back also, in recent releases. [This search for libc6](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+search?text=libc6) (which is the name of the primary binary package that provides libc in Ubuntu) reveals eglibc in releases up to 14.04 LTS Trusty Tahr, then glibc in the subsequent releases 14.10 Utopic Unicorn and 15.04 Vivid Vervet (which is in beta as I write this). See the [eglibc](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eglibc) and [glibc](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc) downstream source package pages for details. *Please feel free to add this information to your answer.*